# Show UI in front of player Unity VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to show a UI always in front of the player, and facing it, in a Unity3D VR project. I am using Unity 2021.3.5f1.

I have a simple UI: a `Canvas`, with a `Panel` and two `TextMeshPro` inside it. The Canvas is child of an empty `GameObject`, with a script in it that manages the UI. The hierarchy is as follows:

[image: UI hierarchi]

My aim is to always show the UI in front of the player, facing the player itself. For this reason I wrote this script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace UI
{
    public class KpPanelManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Transform playerHead;
        [SerializeField] private float spawnDistance = 2f;
        [SerializeField] private float yOffset = 0f;
        
        [SerializeField] private GameObject panel;
        
        private Vector3 _playerHeadForward;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _playerHeadForward = playerHead.forward;
        }

        private void Update()
        {          
            // show the panel in front of the player
            var position = playerHead.position;
            panel.transform.position = position + new Vector3(_playerHeadForward.x, yOffset, _playerHeadForward.z).normalized * spawnDistance;
            
            // rotate the panel to face the player frame by frame
            panel.transform.LookAt(new Vector3(position.x, panel.transform.position.y, position.z));
            panel.transform.forward *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it does not work properly: it is correctly in front of the player, but it does not follow the player's camera itself when it moves. In the Unity editor I am referencing the `Canvas` that contains my UI as the panel `GameObject` in script, and the `MainCamera` of the `XROrigin` as the playerHead `Transform` in the script.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are not smoothing the movement of the canvas, you can just put it under the head in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Transform's [TransformPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) to covert position from local to world space

Something like following would work for your case

```
Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0,0,2); // 2 units in front of camera
panel.transform.position = playerHead.TransformPoint(offset);
```